# Social Media web app. Trying to make a "post" system

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I may have worded the title a bit weird, I am sorry for that.
I am working on a web app that is comparable to LinkedIn for my portfolio, while using unfamiliar tech stack. The tech stack i am using for the backed is Java Spring boot and mysql.

Essentially I am trying to make a system where a User can make a post, similar to LinkedIn:
[LinkedIn example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTQAc.png)

As of right now I have only made my User class and set up my database so that new users get stored in the database. I am assuming I have to do something almost exactly the same but I also know that the "post-like" system needs to be linked with a User. I am a bit unsure of how i can implement it.
Listed below I have the necessary code and file names. Also as a heads up, the User is named as Musician due to the nature of the project. I would appreciate any help I can get and if anything is unclear I can fix or revise! Thanks a bunch in advance.

MusicianController.java

```
package com.chrisandjeffproject.pluggedinbackend.controllers;

import com.chrisandjeffproject.pluggedinbackend.models.Musician;
import com.chrisandjeffproject.pluggedinbackend.repository.MusicianRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class MusicianController {

    @Autowired
    private MusicianRepository musicianRepository;

    //Post request to save the newly made musician in repo
    @PostMapping("/musician")
    Musician newMusician(@RequestBody Musician newMusician) { return musicianRepository.save(newMusician); }

    //Deleting a musician from DB
    @DeleteMapping("/musician/{id}")
    String deleteMusician(@PathVariable Long id) {
        if(!musicianRepository.existsById(id)){
            System.out.println("User with id: " + id + " was not found");
        }

        musicianRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "User with id: " + id + " has been succesfully deleted";
    }

}
```

Musicianrepository.java

```
package com.chrisandjeffproject.pluggedinbackend.repository;

import com.chrisandjeffproject.pluggedinbackend.models.Musician;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface MusicianRepository extends JpaRepository<Musician, Long> {
}
```

Musician.java

```
package com.chrisandjeffproject.pluggedinbackend.models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Musician {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

I haven't tried too much but I did create a PostController class and a PostRepository interface, similar to the Musicians. I believe my problem lies heavily within the Post.java class that will eventually need to be made (i think).

Comment: Hello, you are doing really good! Just go ahead, define the entity class for Post and join both together with a relationship. OneToMany relationship between Musician an Post would be the best choice. Because one Musician can post more then once. Next step after that would be to add some endpoints (REST controller methods) for adding and deleting posts.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! If you don't mind I may have some more questions related to your response.
I have set up the Posts entity (I renamed all classes containing Post to Posts after realizing that Post wouldn't really make much sense lol) and it contains only an Id, String text, and String title as of right now. Is it necessary to make an instance of Musician within the entity?